# Issue with Marker.io seeing half of the screen

Tags: fullscreen, screen-size

I have 2 different websites, and I am using Marker.io to capture bugs in my websites, for some reason Marker.io only sees half of the screen in the second website, but it works fine on the first website. I tried Google how to fix this issue, but couldn't find any solution.

I believe there is some issue within a code, bcuz Chrome extension(Marker.io) works fine on the first website.

Could you help me with this issue?

P.S. I have already Googled and searched here for the solution but there is no any success.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, pretty much someone setted iframe value to 740px i removed that value, and the issue was removed

```
frame {width: 100%}
```